# Is there a general way to determine the Laplacian of the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

I have a real symmetric $3\times3$ matrix $\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r}$) which depends on $\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Each eigenvalue can be considered a scalar field $e_i(\mathbf{r})$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume these functions are differentiable.

A general derivative $\partial e_i(\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{v}_i^T.\partial\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r}).\mathbf{v_i}$ where $\mathbf{v}_i$ is the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $e_i$ and $\partial\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r})$ is the matrix of derivatives of the elements.

Using the above, $\vec{\nabla}e_i(\mathbf{r})$ is straightforward to determine, but $\Delta e_i(\mathbf{r}) = \vec{\nabla}.\vec{\nabla}e_i(\mathbf{r})$ is proving to be a bit more challenging.

I'd be happy with any tips or references.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! How explicitly do you know the eigenvectors? If you actually know them, your best may may be to diagonalize $M$ pointwise and then compute the Laplacian of each diagonal entry. (In a sense, that's what you're already doing, since the eigenvectors are the columns of a diagonalizing matrix....)

Comment: I don't have an explicit expression for the eigenvectors, but I do have an explicit expression for $\mathbf{M}$. Namely, $\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{k,l} r_k r_l C_{ik,lj}$ where C is a rank 4 tensor with symmetries $C_{ij,kl} = C_{kl,ij} = C_{ji,kl}$.